# Return value in string based on another value in SSRS

Tags: string, reporting-services, split

I have a application that uses text templates to ask questions and record answers from end users. The data is stored in a postgres database using HTML. The answers are radio buttons for yes, no, or decline. The HTML string uses a X to mark what answer they chose. An example of the html output is below.

Yes X No Decline

There is a space after the X. I want to return the value after the space.

In this example the answer is No. Other answers may be Yes or Decline depending on where the X is.

How do I evaluate for X and return the Value that follows it (Yes, No or Decline) in a SSRS expression

I've tried doing this in the sql with split_part and regex but am not having luck so I want to try the SSRS side to return the proper value. I've seen examples of instr and mid but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Instr to identify the X for the answer.

Then use the Mid function to grab the part after the X (2 characters including the space after the X, hence the +2).

Rather than waste time figuring out how many characters the answer is or where the next space is, you can just get 3 characters and TRIM the trailing space from the NO answer.

```
=TRIM(Mid(Fields!ANSWER.Value, InStr(Fields!ANSWER.Value, "X") + 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWITCH and Contains() to search for the values as there is only a small finite list.

```
=SWITCH (
    Fields!Answer.Value.Contains("X Yes"), "Yes",
    Fields!Answer.Value.Contains("X No"), "No",
    Fields!Answer.Value.Contains("X Decline"), "Decline",
    True, "Invalid Answer"
    )
```

Here's a quick sample of data and the results .

The dataset query

```
SELECT 'Yes X No Decline' AS Answer UNION
SELECT 'X Yes No Decline' UNION
SELECT 'Yes No X Decline' UNION
SELECT 'Yes No Decline'
```

The results

[image]